# Panel missing overlapped part when menu pop-out

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I made a simple draw rectangle application with `JFrame` and `JPanel`

```
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)jPanel1.getGraphics();

    g2d.setColor(Color.red);
    g2d.drawRect(x,y,w,h);
```

Whenever I draw something and click on menu, the overlapped part disappears

[image]

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: thats in paint or painComponent?

Comment: neither of them, I just get start and end points then use Graphics2D to draw/fill rect

Comment: Well you have to redraw that shape. Thats why paintComponent would be better place for that.

Comment: 1) Please provide a [mcve] so we can also reproduce your wrong behavior. 2) Your approach is probably wrong. Don't use `jPanel1.getGraphics()` but override for your `jPanel1` method `paintComponent` and use the Graphics object from parameter.

Comment: that's nearly everything

Comment: *"that's nearly everything"* Tip: Add @SergiyMedvynskyy (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 2):

As I already said in my comment, never use `jPanel1.getGraphics()`, but overridie the method `paintComponent` instead. This method will always be called when panel is repainted. Here is a small example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

/**
 * <code>PaintExample</code>.
 */
public class PaintExample extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // correct approach
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(20, 20, Math.max(getWidth() - 200, 0), Math.max(getHeight() - 100, 0));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        // required for correct work of JFrame.pack method
        return new Dimension(500, 400);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(PaintExample::createAndShowGUI);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frm = new JFrame();
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu m = new JMenu("File");
        m.add("Test menu item 1");
        m.add("Test menu item 2");
        m.add("Test menu item 3");
        menuBar.add(m);
        frm.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        frm.add(new PaintExample());
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great example! Two minor points unrelated to the fixes you've suggested. 1) I always prefer `frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);` (to `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`). If there are no other threads running, or other windows visible, they will have the same effect. If **not** that situation, it is better to take steps to shut down the thread or deal with other windows. 2) Best practices would suggest starting the GUI on the EDT. It only takes another couple of lines of code (with the lambda expressions) and helps instill good practices.

Comment: @AndrewThompson 1) Good to know. 2) Done.